# In cucumber feature file, scenario outline table can have < >-delimited parameters of Examples

Tags: gherkin, cucumber-java

Please tell me if this is possible to have angle parameter in the table of Example (of Scenario Outline). I am new in feature file development hence need your help.

```
Feature: Testing table can have angle parameter of examples

    Scenario Outline: outline
        When a table step:
            | Day | Months   |
            | 30  | <Months> |
        Then verify if day exist in this month<DoesContainInThisMonth>

        Examples:
            | Months | DoesContainInThisMonth |
            | Jan    | No                     |
            | Feb    | No                     |
            | Mar    | Yes                    |
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "angle parameter"?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a straight solution to this problem the way you are looking for.

But maybe a different approach could help.

To give an example: in the column "Months" you could have a list of months that meet each requirement ("Days"?). And then, check if a specific month is included in this list in the StepDefinitions code. This way, you only need one table.

In my opinion that makes the test more clear, which is one of the benefits of BDD.

If you provide more information about the objective of this scenario, it is likely more contributing answers will come up.